# Conditions within .aspx file for ListView ItemTemplate

Tags: asp.net, listview, if-statement

Is there a way to filter <%Eval("value") %> within ASPX file?

```
 <ItemTemplate>
     <tr class='<%# Container.DataItemIndex % 2 == 0 ? "row" : "row alt" %>'>
        <td class="width-200"><%#Eval("znacka") %></td>
        <td class="width-200"><%#Eval("status") %></td>
        <td><asp:LinkButton ID="btnZnackyDelete" runat="server" Text="delete" CommandName="Delete" /></td>
     </tr>
 </ItemTemplate>
```

I want to show linkbutton only if Eval("status") == 0

is it possible within aspx file? Or how do you specify this within c# code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnZnackyDelete" Visible='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("status").ToString() == "0") %>' runat="server" Text="delete" CommandName="Delete" />
```

Comment: I know this is old, but it is freaking brilliant. I love simple solutions to problems.

Answer (score 0):

Use an if statement, that's easiest.

```
<% if (Eval("value") == 0) { %>
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnZnackyDelete" runat="server" Text="delete" CommandName="Delete" />
<% } %>
```

You can also handle the OnItemDataBound event for the repeater or whatever you are using. In that you can use findcontrol and toggle visibility.

If is by far easier though.