# hide gridview hyperlink in visible property of source rather then code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

Ive got a gridview with an itemtemplate that has a hyperlink control in it.  I want to hide a hyperlink control if its item in the database returned null:

```
  <ItemTemplate>
                                   <asp:HyperLink ID="hlSugar" Visible=<% DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.CaseID")==null %> ToolTip="View the issue in SugarCRM." Target="_blank" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# "http://myPath&record=" + DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.CaseID") %>' Text="Issue"></asp:HyperLink>
                            </ItemTemplate>
```

Not sure on the syntax can I do

```
Visible = <% iif(databinder.eval(container, "dataItem.caseid")==null, false, true) %>
```

Not sure how to get the syntax correct.  I basically want to check if my `DataItem.CaseID is null and hide this field if it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using this:
`Visible='<%# Eval("SugarCaseID") != DBNull.Value %>'`

Answer (score 0):

`visible='<%# Eval("dataItem.caseid") != null) %>'`

Give this a shot

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
bool ShowLink(obj data)
{ 

   if(data!=null) {return true; } return false;
}
```

aspx:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="hlSugar" Visible='<%# ShowLink(Eval("CaseID"))%>' 
 ToolTip="View the issue in SugarCRM." Target="_blank" runat="server" 
 NavigateUrl='<%# "http://myPath&record=" 
 + DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.CaseID") %>' Text="Issue">
</asp:HyperLink>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="hlSugar" Visible='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("DataItem.CaseID").ToString() == "0") %>' ToolTip="View the issue in SugarCRM." Target="_blank" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# "http://myPath&record=" + DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.CaseID") %>' Text="Issue" />
```

REference:
[Conditions within .aspx file for ListView ItemTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5072061/conditions-within-aspx-file-for-listview-itemtemplate)